# add html as option to a variable

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have this code :

```
$variable_name = bla bla bla;
```

I want to add to this variable this code :

```
<a class="screenshot" rel="<?php echo $baseurl.$this->row->image; ?>" >
<div class="photo"></div>
</a>
```

Can somebody PLEASE help?

Thank you

Comment: And why can't you assign it to your variable? Please be more specific

Comment: I receive "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /file.php on line 31" error if I put that code to the variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign it to your variable like any other string. However, since you are already in php mode, you have to remove `<?php ?>`, and use string contatenation operator `.` to include `$baseurl.$this->row->image`

```
$variable_name = '<a class="screenshot" rel="' . $baseurl.$this->row->image . '" >
<div class="photo"></div>
</a>';
```